# Nautilus keeps crashing in 22.04

Tags: nautilus, sync, 22.04

I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04.
Also I use a software called **PowerFolder Sync and Share** to synchronize some folders between my computers (I suspect this has to do with the problem).

Unfortunately, the file explorer (**Nautilus**) now randomly freezes or crashes when I leave it open for some time.
I can only restart it after running `killall nautilus`. It's a bit difficult to debug since it happens randomly and I can't recreate it deliberately.

Any ideas on how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I deleted the tracker3 cache and the problem seems to be solved for now.

```
rm -r ~/.cache/tracker3/
```

Comment: Looks like It's working, Thanks :)

Comment: Why? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

According to information from here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1993907 
the problem might sometimes re-appear.

In such case, you can disable the tracker permanently - by removing "Executable" permission from its binaries, as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73197441/492221

However, you may also try de-indexing directories (or even disable searching in Files in the GNOME settings in the Search section), as described here: 
https://r4ven.fr/en/blog/gnome-nautilus-indexation-tracker-miner/