# Gnome (dragging, application menu, dock etc.) being quite slow after update on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, window-manager, 22.04

I updated to Ubuntu 22.04 today and I noticed that anything related to gnome like window dragging, searching or scrolling through the activity windows, moving my mouse through the dock is quite slow and laggy now.

I already use the proprietary and tested NVIDIA driver and tried to turn different things on and off, also the X.Org X Server driver had the same issues.

Was not able to find the cause of this problem.

Thanks in advance! If you need any further system related information please let me know

Comment: Same here. I didn't have time to investigate why... but yes.. moving windows feels awful and slow

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/22-04-nvidia-drivers/28072 backup you /etc/environment and add > __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 to it. Try it.

Comment: @Dami, `export __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0`. Right?

Answer (score 6):

Changing mouse polling (e.g. using Piper) has fixed this issue for many users.

Nvidia driver 525 or mutter updates in gnome might also fix [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-510/+bug/1970413) which seemed to get worse in 22.04 (see the last comments [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1799679)).

I did both the /etc/environment change as well as the polling change, and restarted. Not sure what fixed it or if it is truly fixed, but right now it feels ok.

**Edit: Leaving the other solutions up, as they have worked for others, but for me... right after doing this, I opened slack and discord. Then I noticed the issue was back.**

closing discord resolved the issue, opening discord then brought it back.

**looking it up, it seems that disabling advanced > hardware acceleration [is a thing](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ud2l2l/comment/itrmjdo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), and seems to have *actually* fixed the issue, thank god.**

crossing fingers, but I really think I nailed it now that I was able to reproduce it so consistently. Didn't realize it was discord since I just always have it running in the background. I suspect it was attaching to the wrong GPU or something? No idea, but jeez, terrible that it can cause every other windows to lag while dragging, what thing.

edit a few days later: the issue is indeed solved for me, this also substantially reduced my CPU usage, which often showed the temps completely maxed out even though the processor and gpu did not show high utilization--I presume it was the iGPU that was being maxed out? anyways, just giving a follow up here.

Comment: Upgrading to 525 did the trick for me. Dragging windows is smooth as butter now.

Comment: Yup, been experimenting with early release on 525. I have a different, similar issue in 525 though--if I have external monitors and am in hybrid mode, there is some stuttering when dragging windows. not quite as bad, but also don't yet see a fix for it.

Answer (score 2):

Open `/etc/environment` e.g.:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Add top line

```
export __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0
```

Directly after this drag and moving windows should be super fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

My NVIDIA driver is on 525.147.05. So, I don't think it is the driver issue. The following is what I have done which solve this issue but I am not sure which one did the trick.

1. add `export __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0` to `/etc/environment`
2. didn't restart the system but restart the gnome shell
3. `rm -rf ~/.cache/tracker3/` and `nautilus --quit`
4. `sudo apt install piper` (https://github.com/libratbag/piper) and set my Logitech mouse report rate to 500 (1000 is the default).

The point 2 is for solving stuck and crashing when dragging files in nautilus. ([Nautilus keeps crashing in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406294/nautilus-keeps-crashing-in-22-04))

Now, my system works really smoothly.