# Nautilus (Files) crashes when trying to open specific folder on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nautilus, files

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoYaf.png)

When I try to open folders (Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos)  using right click on Files icon on the left bar the Files crashes.

I noticed that this only happens when I already have Files opened.
How can I fix this? I was using it quite a lot on 20.04...

Comment: this looks like the same as the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344175/nautilus-crashes-when-trying-to-open-another-window-by-right-clicking-the-nautil), and is a result of a Wayland bug. Switch to Xorg if you need this functionality.

Comment: Have you tried the solution shown in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406294/nautilus-keeps-crashing-in-22-04 ?

Answer (score 8):

This issue is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1934579) that only occurs on Wayland. The workaround is to use Xorg:

1. Log out
2. On the bottom-right of the login screen, there should be a cog wheel icon. Click it, and select "Ubuntu on Xorg"
3. Log in. You will now be using Xorg as your display manager.

Comment: +1; I can't find the cog wheel on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04. But you can switch to Xorg with [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857) from another thread at AskUbuntu.

Comment: when you move the cursor to the bottom right corner, it(cog wheel) shows u[

Comment: I've the same problem also on Ubuntu 22.10. Plus, nautilus also crashes when I search for a file, open a folder by double-clicking it and then use the "Back" button (either on the titlebar or the hardware button on the mouse). Both issues are present also in an Xorg session :( Nor does clearing the tracker3 cache help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use X11, restarting Nautilus by running `nautilus -q` fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is getting rid of completely from nautilus. There are different file manager alternatives. I removed **nautilus** and installed **dolphin** and everything is OK.

Comment: While this might work for you. the question involves nautilus. 

The thing about nautilus in gnome 3 is that it is also largely supported by internal components that are reused by other apps.

So it might not be nautilus itself that has the problem. You'll know this if apps that use the gnome3 file picker also crash in those same folders.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself having the same only for folders containing `.json` files, if I move them to another folder, I am able to open again